# how to do date.toString while keeping the local date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, date

I have used this code to serialized a date js object to a string,

but for `April 12th` date it's translated to `April 11t`.

```
self.dateToString = function (date) {
                    return (date === null || !(date instanceof Date)) ? null : date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    //return (date === null || !(date instanceof Date)) ? null : dateFormat(date, "dd mmmm yyyy");
                }
```

how can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Probably, it's indeed April 11th in UTC time. But you are not showing what original date is (tooltip covers time part of the date). But it's correct most likely.

Comment: Can it be about your browser timezone?

Comment: @dfsq I want to stringily the date only, regardless of timezone. Just the one chosen by the user from the datepicker

Comment: So don't use toISOString then. You can format it manually.

Comment: @dfsq how would you do this?

Comment: Check polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString Just use corresponding non-UTC methods.

Comment: Why `date === null || !(date instanceof Date)`? In what case will the first test return true and the second not also return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firsly set timezone = UTC and then
just add a function to your controller by passing the date -

```
function dateToString (date){
     var d = new Date(date),
     month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
     day = '' + d.getDate(),
     year = d.getFullYear();

 if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
 if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

 return [year, month, day].join('-');
```

}

it will return the date..

it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using Angular and Angular has a nice little filter that can parse JavaScript dates really nicely.

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);
  
  MyController.$inject = ['$filter'];
  function MyController($filter) {
   var vm = this;
    vm.doMagic = function() {
     return vm.dateToString(new Date("04/12/2017"));
    }
    vm.dateToString = function (date) {
      return (date === null || !(date instanceof Date)) ? null : $filter("date")(date, "dd MMMM yyyy");
    }
  }
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as main">
    {{main.doMagic()}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```